# Can anyone please explain this code?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am learning coding on egghead.com but I am having a hard time understanding this code, specifically line 4, where did we define handler?

Thanks!

```
1    var deliveryBoy = {
2    name: "John",

3       handleMessage: function (message, handler) {
4        handler(message);
5      },
6    
7      receive: function () {
8        var that = this;
9    
10        this.handleMessage("Hello, ", function(message) {
11          that.name 
12    
13         console.log(message + that.name);
14        })
15      }
16    }
17    deliveryBoy.receive();
```

Comment: you are asking to explain js in one answer ?

Comment: handler is the variable name assigned to the second argument passed in to the function and is itself a function that can be invoked

Comment: `handler` is a function passed to `handleMessage`. The function is defined at the `this.handleMessage` call. This is a callback function.

Comment: It's the second parameter of the `handleMessage` function, it's defined (and passed) in line 10: where it says `function(message) { ...` JS unlike Java allows for functions to be passed in the parameters of a function...

Comment: `deliveryBoy!=deliverBoy `

Comment: Thanks guys! @Josep tnx!

Answer (score 0):

'handler' is defined on line 3 (it is the second parameter). deliveryBoy.receive is calling deliveryBoy.handleMessage and passing in the data and function. Line 17 is calling deliveryBoy.receive to get the process started. Does this make sense now?

Comment: Thanks, it makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can pass functions as arguments to another function.

in your code snippet, check the line number 10. here you are passing a function as an argument to the handleMessage (whose value is a function) property of the deliveryBoy object.

so now check the line number 3 in your code. handleMessage property is holding a function as its value. this function expects to arguments to be passed(message, handler).
the second argument will be holding the function that is passed in the function invocation at line number 10.